# Junit test class which scans list of classes in a package and verifies whether every method contains begin and close transactions

Tags: java, junit, transactions

I am looking to implement the following functionality.

I need a Junit test class which scans list of classes in a package and verifies whether every method contains begin and close transactions. Any pointers in this regard will is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to answer your question directly because I think you are not going the right way. A better design would *ensure* you the property you want to test. You can do something like :

```
public interface Transaction {
    void initiate() throws Exception;
    void execute() throws Exception;
    void rollBack();
    void close();
}

public TransactionManager {
    public void executeTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
       try {
          transaction.initiate();
          transaction.execute();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          transaction.rollBack();
       } finally {
          transaction.close();
       }
    }
}
```

And then, it becomes easy to test :

```
public class TestTransaction implements Transaction {
    private boolean initiated, executed, rollBacked, closed;

    @Override
    public initiate() { initiated = true; }

    // ...
}

public class FailingTestTransaction extends TestTransaction {
    @Override
    public execute() throws Exception { 
        super.execute(); 
        throw new Exception("Voluntary failure");
    }

    // ...
}

public TransactionManagerTest {
    private TransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       this.transactionManager = new TransactionManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void initiateAndCloseOnNormalExecution() {
        TestTransaction transaction = new TestTransaction();
        transactionManager.executeTransaction(transaction);
        assert(transaction.isInitiated() && transaction.isClosed());
    }

    @Test
    public void initiateRollbackAndCloseOnFailure() {
        TestTransaction transaction = new FailingTestTransaction();
        transactionManager.executeTransaction(transaction);
        assert(transaction.isInitiated() && transaction.isRollbacked && transaction.isClosed());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dici. Actually my requirement is to verify if the transactions which are opened in the java class are closed and not to verify a new transaction in Junit.                                              Requirement Background : In some instances it is observed that transactions which are opened in Java file are either not closed or not handled properly and it impacted the application many times. I am new to Junit and want to know if we can test a scenario in Junit where the transactions opened are closed properly in Java file.

Comment: My answer should show you how to do it. If it doesn't, you probably need to give more details/code